# Black screen at startup (no splash screen) on Android 6.0.1 on Unity 5.3.0

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've a weird problem appearing in my published app, several users reported that the app shows a black screen at startup on android 6 without even showing the splash screen, I had a chance to test it on my friend's mobile (Galaxy S7 Edge) and it does show a black screen and just stops.

I don't have an android 6 device myself so it's hard to debug, but on some research I've done the following and it doesn't help:

- Turned on development build
- Tried almost all texture compression types
- Turned on/off multi-threaded rendering
- Turned on/off auto-graphics API and forced OpenGLES2
- Turned on/off 32-bit display buffer
- Changed splash screen to sprite 2D (don't know how it's relative but I've read it somewhere)

Unity Version: 5.3.0
Used Assets: Cardboard SDK, Image/Contact Picker

Knowing that I have another application developed with the same version and build settings and it works well, almost the only difference that it doesn't contain cardboard SDK..

Naturally I tried building the app without the scenes that used Cardboard even completely removed them, tried another SDK version and it didn't work.
The only other difference between the two is that the second contains scenes with 3D models, again tried removing them and didn't work..

I don't know if it's ok to post the google play link for anyone to try, if it's ok please tell me as I can't debug the application so maybe someone can help..

Thank You,

Comment: for whoever experience this problem - on Unity 2018.4.1f1 just disabling Development Build did the trick and application successfully launched on my 7 years old Acer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Black screen at startup is a result of permission query on Android 6.0(MARSHMALLOW). Permission query method changed on Android Android 6.0. The current and only known solution is to update to Unity 5.4 The fix in this version.

Comment: But again why does my other app work? It requests no additional permissions? :/

Comment: It depends on features/permission requested by your other apps. If the current app requires dangerous permission then it must be done through code which Unity 5.3 does not support.

Comment: @Programmer How did you find out that permission query on startup causes the black screen? I would like to know because I want to dig more into the issue.

Comment: This was a behavior that happened due to the new permission system that was introduced on Android. This permission stuff was done through code instead of Manifest.  **It is now fixed** if you are using Unity 5.4 and above. Also if you are still having this problem, upgrade to the latest version of Unity.